# Line in Modified Bessel Function of the First Kind

Tags: functional-analysis, special-functions, bessel-functions

Plotting the modified Bessel function of the first kind $I_\nu(x)$ as a function of two real variables, it looks like to one side of $x=\frac{2}{3}\nu$ the function falls rapidly to zero and on the other side it increases rapidly. This approximation seems to get better for larger values of $x$ and $\nu$. Is there a theorem that captures this observation?

[image]

Comment: nice question! (+1)